# PHP Unit Test for Function having call to another function using $this Keyword

Tags: phpunit

In PHP i have function like this in which it has a call to another function `searchDateOperator()` with in the same class using `$this` keyword. How to write a Unit test for this?

```
public static function segmetDateRangeFilter($searchField, $startDate, $endDate, $dateRange)
{
    $filter = [];

    if ($startDate && !$endDate) {
        $filter = [
            'range' => [
                $this->searchDateOperator($searchField) => [
                    'gte' => strtotime($startDate),
                ]
            ]
        ];
    }

    if ($endDate && !$startDate) {
        $filter = [
            'range' => [
                $this->searchDateOperator($searchField) => [
                    'lte' => strtotime($endDate)
                ]
            ]
        ];
    }

    if ($startDate && $endDate) {
        $filter = [
            'range' => [
                $this->searchDateOperator($searchField) => [
                    'gte' => strtotime($startDate),
                    'lte' => strtotime($endDate)
                ]
            ]
        ];
    }

    if ($dateRange !== '') {

        // $endTime upto current Time
        $endTime = Carbon::now()->timestamp;
        // Start Time . substract the date range days. and in timestamp
        $startTime = Carbon::now()->subDays($dateRange)->timestamp;

        $filter = [
            'range' => [
                $this->searchDateOperator($searchField) => [
                    'gte' => $startTime,
                    'lte' => $endTime
                ]
            ]
        ];
    }

    if ($filter) {
        return $filter;
    }
}
```

Comment: just as usually -- test if actually returned value for given set of `$searchField`, `$startDate`, `$endDate`, `$dateRange` is same as expected. or there is anything else that makes this impossible?

Comment: it has the function searchDateOperator to be called with this is fuction needs to be tested.... In test function i simply call this function it throws the error Error: Using $this when not in object context.... But if change the call using the scope resolution operator it works fine...  The problem is i want to call the function which has referrence to another function using $this

Comment: yeah, i missed `segmetDateRangeFilter` is static so you call it as static. This imposes `searchDateOperator` to be static too (otherwise just does not make sense). So changing `$this->searchDateOperator($searchField)` to `self::searchDateOperator($searchField)` should do.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the method is declared static but you are using `$this`. If the method you are calling is static as well you should use self or static, like this:

```
$filter = [
    'range' => [
        self::searchDateOperator($searchField) => [
            'gte' => $startTime,
            'lte' => $endTime
        ]
    ]
];
```

Alternatively you could remove static from segmetDateRangeFilter and use it in a test like this:

```
public function testSomething()
{
    $filterFactory = new DateFilterFactory();
    // ...

    $result = $filterFactory->segmetDateRangeFilter(...);

    // Assertions against result
}
```

The class name `DateFilterFactory` you have to replace with whatever you use.